# Error : Undifined Variable when creating new file

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a new `.php` file using php. But I get the following error:

> **error : Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\create\index.php on line 4.**

Here is the sample code :

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("koneksi.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $txt = "<?php $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'crm');
                  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta'); 
           ?>";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: variables are replaced by their values in strings with double quotes `"`, try with simple quotes instead `'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put variable within double quotes PHP will print its value, and if it is not defined it will throw a notice.

If you want `$conn` to be part of your string you need to put in within single quotes.

```
$txt = '<?php $conn=mysqli_connect(\'localhost\', \'root\', \'\', \'crm\');
                date_default_timezone_set(\'Asia/Jakarta\'); 
  ?>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Either switch from double quotes to single quotes for your $txt variable - e.g.

```
$txt = '<?php $conn=...';
```

Or escape your dollar sign with a backslash